Unable to reset GCP Computer Engine VM password - Windows password could not be set
I have one VM in Google Cloud that I am trying to reset the password but get this error. I even tried creating a new one and waited for like 30 minutes but still not even able to do this on newly created one as well.
Have tried the cli shell command as well in Google shell still no luck.
Windows password could not be set. Try again. If you just created this instance, allow 10 minutes for it to be ready.
Tried creating new one. Using google shell cli commands assigning roles.

I suggest you to please check the logs in cloud logging.
